# How can I get programmatic access to the "Date taken" field of an image or video using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying convert a bunch of pictures and videos, but when I convert it to a new format I obviously lose the properties of the original file. I'd like to be able to read the "Date taken" property from the old file and update it on the new one using powershell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't test it right now (don't have any images with XIF data laying around, but I think this should work:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
$pic = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap('C:\PATH\TO\SomePic.jpg')
$bitearr = $pic.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value 
$string = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bitearr) 
$DateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($string,"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`0",$Null)
$DateTime
```

Comment: This is half the story I can get the dateTken from a picture, how about a video (mpg, wmv)?

Comment: Hmm...I'll do some poking around. I'm not sure to be honest.

Comment: This returns a bite array. To convert this to [datetime] you will need to do the following: ``$bitearr = $pic.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value $string = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bitearr) [datetime]::ParseExact($string,"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`0",$Null)``

Comment: Alternatively omit the null character from the array using `$bitearr[0..18]` and use `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss` as the date pattern ... you can also now use `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing` instead of reflection.

Comment: Caveat - This code only works on Windows, and not PowerShell 7 on non-Windows hosts

Answer (score 7):

In general, you can access **any** extended property for a file shown in explorer through the shell [`GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870.aspx) method. Here's a short example, adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349030/2495):

```powershell
$file = Get-Item IMG_0386.jpg
$shellObject = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$directoryObject = $shellObject.NameSpace( $file.Directory.FullName )
$fileObject = $directoryObject.ParseName( $file.Name )

$property = 'Date taken'
for(
  $index = 5;
  $directoryObject.GetDetailsOf( $directoryObject.Items, $index ) -ne $property;
  ++$index ) { }

$value = $directoryObject.GetDetailsOf( $fileObject, $index )
```

However, according to [the comments on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c#comment-2600079), there is no general-purpose mechanism for **setting** these properties. The [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class that [EBGreen mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6834500/2495) will work for images, but I'm afraid I also do not know of a .NET option for video files.

Comment: So how does this work for the date taken attribute, specifically?

Comment: `$property = 'Date taken'` is used to find the index of the "Date taken" property, and the shell objects are used to read that property for the file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, thanks to the above help and others.

```
try{
Get-ChildItem C:\YourFolder\Path | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq '.jpg'} |
ForEach-Object {
         
        $path = $_.FullName
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
        $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($path)
        $propertyItem = $bitmap.GetPropertyItem(36867) 
        $bytes = $propertyItem.Value 
        $string = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes) 
        $dateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($string,"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`0",$Null)

        $bitmap.Dispose()

        $_.LastWriteTime = $dateTime
        $_.CreationTime = $dateTime
        }}
finally
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read **and write** the "date taken" property of an image, use the following code (building on the answer of @EBGreen):

```
try
{
    $path = "C:\PATH\TO\SomePic.jpg"
    $pathModified = "C:\PATH\TO\SomePic_MODIFIED.jpg"

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($path)
    $propertyItem = $bitmap.GetPropertyItem(36867) 
    $bytes = $propertyItem.Value 
    $string = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes) 
    $dateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($string,"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`0",$Null)
   
    $dateTimeModified = $dateTime.AddDays(1) # Set new date here
    $stringModified = $dateTimeModified.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`0",$Null)
    $bytesModified = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($stringModified) 

    $propertyItem.Value = $bytesModified
    $bitmap.SetPropertyItem($propertyItem)
    $bitmap.Save($pathModified)
}
finally
{
    $bitmap.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell function, `Get-DateTaken`, retrieves the date when a file was taken or as fallback created. It uses the Windows Shell COM object to access file properties that aren't directly accessible through .NET's System.IO classes.

This function is more versatile than using `System.Drawing` for a couple of reasons:

It can be used with any type of file, not just image files. `System.Drawing` is primarily used for working with images, so it may not be able to retrieve the "Date taken" property for other types of files.

```
function Get-DateTaken {
    [OutputType([datetime])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $file
    )

    # $DateFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'
    $DateTakenWinApi = 12
    $DateCreatedWinApi = 4

    if ($null -eq $Shell) {
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
    }
 
    $dir = $Shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
    $DateTakenString = $dir.GetDetailsOf($dir.ParseName($_.Name), $DateTakenWinApi)
    if ($DateTakenString -eq '') {
        $DateTakenString = $dir.GetDetailsOf($dir.ParseName($_.Name), $DateCreatedWinApi)
    }
    # sanitze string
    $DateTakenString = $DateTakenString -replace '[^0-9\.\:\ \/]', ''
    # parse to DateTime
    $DateTaken = Get-Date $DateTakenString # -Format $DateFormat
    $DateTaken
}
```

With synopsis:
https://gist.github.com/dhcgn/90c6677f2d6c5c70c123b050b9f9a310